# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (Error Number: 1064)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm keep getting this error (check bottom of question for exact error) I've check again and again but could not find what is wrong. It seems all right. On **insert_batch** its working fine but on **update_batch** i get this error. Here is my current code

**Codeigniter Model**: 
Here is the model which is fetching data correctly

```
    function get_seeds($tournament_id) {
        $this->db->where('tournament_id', $tournament_id);
        $result = $this->db->get('tournament_seed');
        return $result->result();
    }
```

**Codeigniter Controller**: 
Here is my controller where I check if there is and row for seed. If YES than update otherwise insert.

```
    $check_seeds = (object)$this->tournament_model->get_seeds($tournament_id);
    if ($_POST) {
        foreach ($check_seeds as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($key) && !empty($value)) {
                $seeded[] = array(
                    'id' => $value->id,
                    'tournament_id' => $tournament_id,
                    'stage_id' => $stage_id,
                    'seed_id' => $value,
                    'team_name' => $key,
                );
                $this->db->update_batch('tournament_seed', $seeded, 'id');
                redirect('organizer/tournaments);
            } else {
                //something
            }
        }
    }
```

**Print_r($check_seeds)**

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 1
            [team_name] => -V-ATTAX
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 2
            [team_name] => NIP
        )

        [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [tournament_id] => 713161746
            [stage_id] => 3
            [seed_id] => 3
            [team_name] => fnatic
        )
    )
```

**Errors**

```
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: 4096

    Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

    Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

    Line Number: 1970

    Backtrace:

    File: E:\xampp\htdocs\hltv\application\controllers\organizer\Tournaments.php
    Line: 1065
    Function: update_batch

    File: E:\xampp\htdocs\hltv\index.php
    Line: 315
    Function: require_once


    Error Number: 1064

    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE `seed_id` END, `team_name` = CASE WHEN `id` = '4' THEN '1' ELSE `team_name' at line 7

    UPDATE `tournament_seed` SET `tournament_id` = CASE WHEN `id` = '4' THEN '713161746' ELSE `tournament_id` END, `stage_id` = CASE WHEN `id` = '4' THEN '3' ELSE `stage_id` END, `seed_id` = CASE WHEN `id` = '4' THEN ELSE `seed_id` END, `team_name` = CASE WHEN `id` = '4' THEN '1' ELSE `team_name` END WHERE `id` IN('4')

    Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/hltv/system/database/DB_driver.php

    Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use *update_batch()* on the same data you just queried from the database table *tournament_seed*, but you are not using the new *$_POST* data to update.

You also use *update_batch()* within the loop, which is wrong. The loop is just to create the array you want to update, then outside the loop you *update_batch()*

use the following to create an array, which later can be used for *update_batch()*, something like:

```
$seeded=array();
$sd=array();        
foreach($_POST['your_newly_posted_seeds'] as $key=>$value){
    $sd['id']=$value->id;
    $sd['tournament_id']=$tournament_id;
    //...
    array_push($seeded, $sd);
}

$this->db->update_batch('tournament_seed', $seeded, 'id');
```

[update_batch() from the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), scroll down or search: *$this->db->update_batch()* as there is no bookmark to it.